# paging an unbound gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, visual-studio-2010, gridview

can anyone point me to any good examples of how to page an unbound gridview?
Im binding it to a LINQ search query generated on a buttons click event.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working using

```
 protected void grid_PageIndexChanging1(object sender,                                          GridViewPageEventArgs e)  
  {      grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
     grid.DataBind();  
  }
```